Subject: Issue with Configuring SPI on Jetson Nano for Servo Motor Control via Arduino Nano
I am currently working on a project where I need to control a servo motor using Jetson Nano and Arduino Nano. The servo motor is connected to the Arduino Nano, and I am sending commands from the Jetson Nano to the Arduino. However, I am facing an issue when trying to configure SPI on the Jetson Nano.
I've followed some guides and tried to use the command sudo /opt/jetson-io/jetson-io.py to configure the SPI pins. However, when I run this command, the terminal window immediately flashes and closes, preventing me from configuring the expansion header for SPI.
Could anyone please help me with this issue? I would appreciate any advice or guidance on how to resolve it.
Jetson nano specifications:
Package: nvidia-jetpack
Version: 4.6.1-b110
Architecture : arm64
Thank you in advance!
i need a way to slove my mentioned issue
enter image description here this is the problem that No DTB file. even i have file in y system in the boot folder
